# it is possible to turn gtid_mode off on Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is it possible to turn GTID mode off on 2nd generation Cloud SQL instances?  I tried a dynamic change and got the "Super" error message:

```
mysql> SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_MODE = OFF;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) 
for this operation
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer “No”, it is not possible to set the 'gtid_mode' to off on a Cloud SQL 2nd Generation instance. In fact, modifying this parameter requires the “Super” privileges which are disabled for Cloud SQL instances as stated on this MySQL root user account [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#root-user).

Note that 'gtid_mode' is used when binary logging is enabled to prevent data loss during replica creation and failover. It is [recommended](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-announce/0-lti-H3crE) you migrate your queries to work with GTID as this is now a default setting on all Cloud SQL instances.

Lastly, if you require super level access, you can host a custom SQL instance on Google [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/).